# eXist-db include html template in .xq data

Tags: html, templates, xquery, exist-db

i have an index.html data where I included the template through:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-template="templates:surround" data-template-with="templates/page.html" data-template-at="content">
```

At the index html site I included a keyword search form, and the idea is when I click on the search button it should call an .xq file to request the search results:

```
<form method="GET" action="ksearch.xq">
```

When I submit the form, the ksearch.xq page opens, but even though I include the same template div as above:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-template="templates:surround" data-template-with="templates/page.html" data-template-at="content">
```

The ksearch.xq page does not have the template applied.

It seems that when I call an .xq file the template is not applied, but when I call a plain HTML file, the template is applied.

So the question is how can I use this template also in output of an .xq file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

eXist-db's templating framework, by default, operates on requests for files with the `.html` file extension, not for `.xq` files.  As you have found, the templating framework passes results from non-`.html` files through unchanged.  (You will see the special handling for `.html` files if you open the `controller.xql` file in the app's collection.)  Thus, instead of `ksearch.xq`, have your form submit the search parameters to an `.html` file that uses the templating framework's conventions to call XQuery code, e.g.,

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-template="templates:surround" data-template-with="templates/page.html" data-template-at="content">
    <div class="app:show-search-results"/>
</div>
```

This `app:show-search-results` class (which I made-up) would point to a function in the `app` module (in `/db/apps/myapp/modules/app.xqm`) called show-search-results(), with the conventional arguments as used elsewhere in template functions.  This is where you would put your search XQuery code.